# How to input text in iframe? Encountered issue Element must be user-editable in order to clear it

Tags: robotframework

This is my script:

```
Open Admin Dropdown If Closed
Click Element If Visible    ${Liferay_adminDropdownSiteAdministrationLink}
Verify Text Present    Web Content
Click Element If Visible    ${SiteAdministration_addDropdown}
Click Element If Visible    ${SiteAdministration_basicWebContent}
Verify Text Present    New Web Content
Input    ${SiteAdministration_webContentTitleField}    ${newWebContentTitle}
Comment    Select Frame    ${SiteAdministration_webContentContentField}
Comment    Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${SiteAdministration_webContentContentField}
Click Element If Visible    ${SiteAdministration_webContentContentField}
Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${SiteAdministration_webContentContentField}
Input Text    ${SiteAdministration_webContentContentField}    ${newWebContentDescription}
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: @BryanOakley InvalidElementStateException: Message: invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.

Comment: So it seems that the problem isn't related to the frame, it's that you're trying to clear a non-editable element. Are you using a framework such as react or angular?

Comment: what does it mean @BryanOakley?